# If $f$ is a bijection and $f(D) = E$, show that $f^{-1}(E) = D$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $f$ be a function from $A$ to $B$ and let $D\subseteq A$ and $E\subseteq B$.
>
> If $f$ is a bijection and $f(D) = E$, show that $f^{-1}(E) = D$.

This statement can be easily seen to be true by an analogy using the arrow diagram. But how do i prove this statement using element argument, i.e. $f^{-1}(E) \subseteq D$ and $D\subseteq f^{-1}(E)$.

Comment: Have you tried to show these inclusions by just taking an element in one set and showing it's also an element of the other?

Comment: Also, I don't know why you want to do it like that. The map $f$ is a bijection, so in particular the restriction to any subspace is a bijection onto the image of the restriction, since it's injective since $f$ is, and surjective since you take the codomain to be the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $x\in f^{-1}(E)$ then there is $y\in E$ such that $x= f^{-1}(y)$ so $ y=f(x)$. Since $y\in E= f(D)$ there is $z\in D $ such that $y=f(z)$. Since $f$ is injective we see that $x=z$ so $x\in D$. So we have $$f^{-1}(E) \subseteq D$$

Now take any $x\in D$, then $y=f(x)\in E$, but then $x= f^{-1}(y)$ so $x\in f^{-1}(D)$. So we have also: $$D \subseteq f^{-1}(E)$$

This means that $$f^{-1}(E) =D$$